# Images getting corrupt automatically

Tags: images

I had switched theme of my blog, but  when i opend my blog i saw there that thumbnail of posts( featured image) are not showing up.

I moved to my old theme back but images are still corrupt showing. However when i'm opening my posts every image is there showing perfectly.

I'm also unable to upload new image from my media section because after uploading it gets corrupt automatically.

My blog is http://mytechflow.com
Plz help me guyz.

Comment: Are the images themselves corrupt or are the `URL`s wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check/fix the URLs for the images; they are relative URLs, not absolute.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what javascript is loading on your site and the errors.

Comment: If it's url problem then why uploading image is getting corrupt......?

Answer (score 0):

Additional step would be to make sure you have not reached the hosting disk space and images are within the allowed *upload_max_filesize*, which is typically 2mb.